# Where is node_modules directory?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

If I create a new AWS instance (ubuntu 16.04 LTS) and create a directory (NodeT) then run the 2 commands:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

( from https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/ )

I then have successfully installed node and npm?

```
node -v
npm -v
```

return their versions.

So have I created it locally on NodeT or globally on the whole system?
Where is the node_modules directory?

I am trying to install mongodb on the system and am having troubles. I believe I need to run:

```
nodejs node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js
npm rebuild node-sass
```

( from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1579 )
to solve my problems, but the command can't find the node_modules directory and either can I.

I'm clearly missing the basic concept of nodejs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"I'm clearly missing the basic concept of nodejs"* - yep, lots of tutorials out there.

Comment: **npm root -g** for the global node_modules directory.

Answer (score 14):

type this command in your terminal

```
sudo npm root -g
```

Output (example):

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```